# Controller returning login form while returning file with Symfony 5

Tags: security, pdf-generation, symfony5

I have a security problem using Symfony5.
I have configured security.yml:

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/login$, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

Everything works fine, except when I try to load a file (PDF), even if the route is allowed. The pdf shows the login form, but I'm already logged.
I feel it's because I return a File object in my controller:

```
public function viewpdf($id, \Knp\Snappy\Pdf $snappy) {
    // some code

    // load the file from the filesystem
    $file = new File($path_file);

    // display the file contents in the browser instead of downloading it
    return $this->file($file, $file_name, ResponseHeaderBag::DISPOSITION_INLINE);
}
```

Same problem with another controller when I want to force download:

```
return new PdfResponse(
    $snappy->getOutput($pageUrl),
    $file_name
);
```

How can I view and download my pdf while I'm already logged in?
Thank you,

Comment: Are you in dev environment? What does the profiler say?

Comment: I think the problem comes from knp bundle generating my pdf. I give it a route to generate and when knp calls the route to generate the file, it doesn't have the login information. The solution is to find a way to give the session information to this bundle...

Answer (score -1):

OK, I found the solution to this problem, for both cases:

```
// Inside controller

// KNP bbundle does not have the login/session data
$session = $this->get('session');
$session->save();
session_write_close();
$PHPSESSID =$this->get('session')->getId();

$output = $snappy->getOutput($pageUrl, array(
    'cookie' => array(
        'PHPSESSID' => $PHPSESSID
    )));

if($download == 1) {
    return new PdfResponse($output, $file_name);
} else {
    return new Response(
        $output, 200,
        array(
            'Content-Type'          => 'application/pdf',
            'Content-Disposition'   => sprintf('filename="%s"', $file_name)
        )
    );
}
```